# NetworkStream.Read() produce repetitive bytes when reading in loop

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm reading all `DataAvailable`from `NetworkStream` in a `while` loop and in every cycle I'm reading available data with a specific `chunk` size:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("server address", 23);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

byte[] data = new byte[2048]; // read in chunks of 2KB
int bytesRead;
string output = "";

do
{
    bytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    output += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
} while (stream.DataAvailable);

return output;
```

Problem is in output I get some random texts from middle of my received bytes, I mean something similar to this:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
6 F
7 G
8 H
9 I
10 J //here my output must finish but random bytes from middle append to the end:
3 C //repetitive bytes
4 D //repetitive bytes
5 E //repetitive bytes
```

What makes me confused is that if I increase chunk size from `2048` to `3072` this problem will not happen.

I also traced `TcpClient.Available` with a breakpoint in each cycle:

```
First cycle -> 4495
Second cycle -> 2447
Third cycle -> 399
Forth cycle -> 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have thought that this:

```
output += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
```

should be this:

```
output += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);
```

That ensures that only data read on this specific occasion will be included in the output.